# Add Conditional formatting and ignore cells with period

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a column with results of D4/E4, since some E4 values are zero, I have =IFERROR(D4/E4,"."), to enter . instead of #VALUE.
I want to conditional format cells that have values higher or lower than a specific cell (D50), and D51 respectively in my worksheet but when I do so, all cells with . are highlighting, how do I get this done in Excel 2016? 
Thanks

Comment: What formula did you use in conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Formula to determine which cell to format with conditional formatting, If column F is the column that you want to Highlight, select the cells and use Conditional Formatting, New Rule, Use Formula to determine which Cell to Format and write:

```
=OR(AND(F1<$D$51,F1<>"."),AND(F1>$D$50,F1<>"."))
```

and format as you like.
You can change the formula to correspond to your conditions